# Part of certain images missing when retrieved from SQL server

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to retrieve images stored in an SQL server (the actual imagedata is stored in the databse), however certain images have parts of them missing; e.g. the bottom half of certain images are missing while some of them are displayed properly.

The code im using is the below:

```
<?php


$serverName = "TESTSERV\SQLEXPRESS";
$database = "test";
$user = "user";
$password="password";
$DSN_general="odbc-test";
$conn_general=odbc_connect($DSN_general, $user, $password);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM InetDb.dbo.IndivImages WHERE IndivNdx = 6 AND TenantNdx = 41";
$sql_run = odbc_exec($conn_general,$sql);
$row = odbc_fetch_array($sql_run);

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');


echo $row['UserImage'];

?>
```

the table **InetDb.dbo.IndivImages** contains the following fields:

- TanantNdx: tinyint type
- IndivNdx: smallint type
- UserImage: Image type

Might be a silly question but I couldn't find much help about this. Any idea on why I'm being faced with this problem?

Comment: maybe you could add a description of your `InetDb.dbo.IndivImages` table ?

Comment: @JuniusRendel: Updated the details of the IndivImages table in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The data type size of your column InetDb.dbo.IndivImages is probably too short.

Most images render from top to bottom, with the exception of some interlaced image types. Some smaller images manage to fit in your database and some don't, so the binary data gets cut off and they are rendered with missing bottom part.

Maybe [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2ab802a5-5773-43df-a274-9e49bd445498/sql-server-express-image-data-type-max-size?forum=adodotnetdataproviders) can help you?

Also it's not the best idea to store images in the database, especially in SQL server which is limited to 10GB (I think?) per DB.

Comment: Totally agree on not storing images in DB except in some VERY specific use cases (like needing to perform binary search against image data).

Comment: Thanks for your input @Marcin Wasilewski. The image is inserted into the SQL Server through another system.

It seems that only 4 KB of the image is being displayed. Can this be changed ?

Comment: Perhaps check if you can insert more than 4 KB of data into the table manually. If so, it's most likely the other system's fault, not the database itself. If you cannot, then I would start googling how to increase max data size of a column in SQL express (sorry, I'm no expert at it)